# Max sum of k contiguous subarrays

Tags: algorithms, optimization, substrings

The question is: given an array of size $n$ and a number $m$, now our goal is to find AT MOST $m$ contiguous subarrays such that the sum of all these subarrays is the largest. It is also required that none of these subarrays can overlap.

Example: for an array `[1, 2, 3, -2, 3, -10, 3]`, if $m = 2$, then the subarrays we take are `[1, 2, 3, -2, 3]` and `[3]`, and their total sum is 10.

If $m = 4$, given the same array, then the subarrays we end up taking are `[1, 2, 3]`, `[3]` and `[3]` and their total sum is 12 (we don't need the 4th subarray here).

Anyone has a solution?

--Edited
I do have a dumb solution.
First, write a helper function `maxSum()` that finds the max sum subset within an interval of the array using [Kadane’s algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/) (linear runtime).

Then, construct a `dp[]` array with size $n$, where `dp[i]` stores the largest value of sum of contiguous subarray within the interval $[0, i]$.

```
dp[i] = maxSum(0, i)
```

Lastly, repeat this step for $m - 1$ times:

```
for each i: 0 <= i < n:
  for each k: 0 <= k < i:
    dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[k] + maxSum(k + 1, i))
```

This solution is $O(n^2  m)$ in runtime and $O(n^2)$ in space if we store results from `maxSum()` in advance, and $O(n^3  m)$ in runtime $O(n)$ in space if we do not store it in advance. I believe there is definitely a way to do better.